# Can I make the font size in my NERDTree window smaller than in all other windows of Vim?

Tags: gvim, vimrc, nerdtree

Can I make the font size in my `NERDTree` window smaller than in all other windows of `gvim`?

I like large font size of 15 but I'd like the folder tree window of `NERDTree` to be 12 - is this possible to set in `_vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

Should not be possible because of `gvim` just rendering the normal vim console output and the font size can't be changed in a specific zone in a terminal.

Comment: ok - thanks: I've posted a similar question on SO as most things are possible